# jQuery/JS page loading

Tags: jquery, image, loading

I taked a search over the website, but I couldn't find what exactly I want.

So I want when the page loads to display AJAX loader iamge (for example), not to stay white...

Please give more detailed code, I'm new.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

  var ajax_load = "<img src='images/loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";
  $('body').html(ajax_load);
    var postData = $("#form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxpage.php",
            data: postData,
            success: function(body){
            $('body').html(body);
            }
        });
});
```

I believe that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Structurally, it would be something like this:

1. Load the DOM with empty containers, including the "loader image"
2. Load javascript files which load your content and fills the containers
3. Attach javascript event handlers to all links to override the default behavior of loading a new page

But you will be better off using some sort of framework for it. "Hash bang" (#!) is a popular pattern, make a google search for it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To make it more apparent, imagine we have HTML page with this markup:

```
<button id="btnLoad">Load Content</button>
<div id="content">
  Please click "Load Content" button to load content.
</div>
```

We want to load content when a user clicks on the "Load Content" button. So we need to bind a click event to that button first and make AJAX request only after it is fired.

```
$("#btnLoad").click(function(){
    // Make AJAX call
    $("#content").load("http://example.com");
});
```

he above code loads contents from http://example.com into the . While the page is being loaded we want to display our animated GIF image in the "content". So we could further improve our code like so:

```
$("#btnLoad").click(function(){

  // Put an animated GIF image insight of content
  $("#content").empty().html('<img src="loading.gif" />');

  // Make AJAX call
  $("#content").load("http://example.com");
});
```

The .load() function would replace our loading image indicator with the loaded content.

You might be using jQuery’s other AJAX functions like $.ajax(), $.get(), $.post(), in this case use their callback function to remove loading image/text and append your loaded data.

Here is also the solution for having the content hidden until the ajax call is completed to reveal it.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
     #content 
     {
         display:none;
         }
</style>
```

jQ:

```
$(function () {

            var loadingImg = $('#loadingImage');
            loadingImg.show();

            $.ajax({
                url: "secondpage.htm",
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    loadingImg.hide();
                    $("#content").append(html).fadeIn();
                }
            });

        });
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <img src="loader.gif" id='loadingImage' alt='Content is loading. Please wait' />
    <div id='content'>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you make it, to be only when the page loads, no to click button to show the content, just when the page loads...
*Thanks for the detailed code with description!

Comment: Yeah sure. Just wrap it instead of being in click function just to be in $(function(){//executes as soon as the page is ready  });

Comment: But I need it only when the page loads and where I give the loading picture? I need to show the loading picture, only when the page loads- instead of showing white screen...

Comment: Ah i see. Well you can put everything else in a wrapper that's hidden. and when the page loads user only sees the ajax loader image/message. then once the ajax call has succeeded you can make the content visible. But pay attention that by doing this you rely on JS being enabled for your website to be usable. so maybe thinking of a graceful fall-back mechanism would be advantageous.

Comment: No problem. I will check the topic later. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant I added what you wanted to the answer of the question. the last section